# Running eventbridge from S3 into a glue workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge

I am creating a template through a cloudformation so that when inserting a specific file to a specific bucket a rule is executed in eventbridge that triggers a glue workflow execution event.
The problem is that everything I insert into that bucket, whatever the file or if I even create a new forlder, triggers the event.

My resources:

```
S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: bucket-data-test-jp

  EventRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: NotifyEventGluePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: Allow
                Action: glue:notifyEvent
                Resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:accountId:workflow/workflow-move-files-to-s3
        -
          PolicyName: GetObjectS3Policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - s3:GetObject
                  - s3:GetObjectAcl
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-test-jp/source/*

  WorkFlowGlue: It's not important

  ScheduledJobsTrigger: It's not important
   
  EventRuleMoveToS3:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventBusName: default
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.s3
        detail-type:
          - Object Created
        detail:
          bucket:
            name:
              - bucket-data-test-jp
          key:
            prefix:
              - source/eventbridge.yaml
      Name: porcloudformation
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Id: test
          Arn: >-
            arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:accountId:workflow/workflow-move-files-to-s3
          RoleArn: !GetAtt EventRole.Arn
```

My event pattern in eventbridge:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["bucket-data-test-jp"]
    },
    "object": [{
      "prefix": "source/eventbridge.yaml"
    }]
  }
}
```

I already tried with suffix and it doesn't work for me either

I need that the eventbridge rule be executed only when a specific file is inserted in this case eventbridge.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Following rule seems to be working for me. For some reason, specifying `prefix` and `suffix` do not seem to do the intended filtering.

```
{
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "account": ["account-id"],
  "region": ["us-east-1"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["bucket-name"]
    },
    "reason": ["PutObject"],
    "object": {
      "key": ["source_go/eventbridge_go.yaml"]
    }
  }
}
```